# cant install themes after upgrade

Tags: theming, installation

I've upgraded from  D6.31 to D7 . few problems with block.tpl.php in te deafult theme, but sorted easily. 
Now when I install a theme i get a WSOD

```
select * FROM watchdog ORDER by wid DESC lIMIT 2;
```

gives an error of

```
The file %path was not deleted, because it does not exist. | a:1:{s:5:"%path";s:43:"temporary://marinelli-7.x-3.0-beta11.tar.gz";}
```

google hasnt thrown up any possible solutions. Anyone know ?

Comment: The error seems to stem from the `file_unmanaged_delete` function. Does the file actually exist in your temp folder?

Answer (score 0):

hmmmm . When i try it today i get an error message in the browser. I thought I had turned on error reporting in php.ini yesterday.

OS ubuntu 14. all the webdirectory is chown www-data: www-data . 
ive tried chmodding the themes directory to 777 but I still get the error.

ive just got one user, I assume admin privileges havent changed with the upgrade

Warning: move_uploaded_file(/tmp/marinelli-7.x-3.0-beta11.tar.gz): failed to open stream: Permission denied in drupal_move_uploaded_file() (line 1639 of /var/www/devsite.org/includes/file.inc).
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpgdOHHS' to '/tmp/marinelli-7.x-3.0-beta11.tar.gz' in drupal_move_uploaded_file() (line 1639 of /var/www/devsite.org/includes/file.inc).
File upload error. Could not move uploaded file.